# Cant figure out whether Lithium or Strontium is in my substance?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy, elemental-analysis

So for uni I got a substance and I have to basically figure out which anions and cations are in it. I get two chances to guess otherwise I get a new substance and have to start from scratch.

Anyway yesterday I made my first guess:
Cations: Kalium, Ammonium and Lithium
Anions: Chloride

My anion was correct however they said either CO3, NO3, or SO3 is in there as well. I tested negative for all 3 of them, so not sure how to continue here.

My main issue though is the cations:
-Ammonium, this one Im sure about. I did the test with those two circle glasses where you put ph-paper on one side and NaOH with my substance on the other and then put them together. Did that multiple times, the paper turned blue in seconds every time.

-Kalium, semi sure on this one. I mixed it with HOAc and Na3(Co(NO2)6 and it turned yellow-orange. I put in the centrifuge after and its precipitation was yellow as well. Any opinions on the thrustworthiness of this test?

-Lithium, now this one I feel is the wrong one, because I did the flame colour test and as you all know its dark red looks the same as Sr. Since I have absolutely no idea how to differentiate them I just guessed Lithium. Please if you have any idea how test for either of them, help me out because I dont know how continue. I might just guess Sr for my second try.

Comment: You're asking us to do what your TA / instructor should be doing in the seminar belonging the to he lab course: Teaching qualitative wet inorganic analysis. You're welcome to ask about a specific issue with one of the tests, but we can't give a lecture that easily takes half a semester here.

Comment: Anyway welcome to the ion lottery! We've all been there ... ;)

Comment: Lol thank you! Yes Im aware its just that the instructors most of the time are no help at all so I appreciate any other help I can get. Like yesterday I wanted to test for Kalium Cations and the instructions said to use Kaliumchromate. But we only have Kaliumdichromate in the lab. So I asked my instructor if I could use that as well. Instead of answering he told me that is a good question, find out by yourself and then explain it to me. Any chance you could help me with that one? I cant find the answer googling; the instructor wont help and I dont know where else to look.

Comment: Keep in mind the recommended chemical name is potassium,instead of kalium.

Comment: Lithium is more magenta-colored, while strontium is bright red.

Comment: I failed lol but thank you anyway. Turns out it wasnt either strontium or Lithium, it was both which I hadnt even considered and explains why I wasnt able to tell them apart. They really said f^ck you with this substance lol

Answer (score 5):

Lithium produces a red purple flame with only one big line in the spectrum. Strontium produces an orange flame with plenty of lines in the red, orange, yellow and green region of the spectrum. Lithium has no lines in the green. The color of the flames are not the same. Sr is orange red. Lithium is more red purple.

You may also test the solutions of your substances. Solutions of lithium salts do not react when adding a sulfate solution (like sodium sulfate $\ce{Na2SO4}$). Solutions containing strontium ions produced a white precipitate of insoluble strontium sulfate $\ce{SrSO4}$.

Comment: So if I solve my substance in water and add Na2SO4 or any other Sulfate and white precipitate is produced I can safely assume that it is Strontium and not Lithium?

Comment: Yes. Adding some sulfate ions to an aqueous solution is a proof that the solution contains strontium, baryum or lead (and calcium in concentrated solutions)